# Creating a responsive row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive row that, when displayed on an iPad, the 3 images go across the screen like on desktop. Currently they are behaving like they are on mobile and expanding vertically, not horizontally.

The images are the 3 product range images on the website: http://dekatest.neto.com.au/

```html
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="row"><img alt="" src="/assets/images/MEDICAL-RANGE.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" /><img alt="" src="/assets/images/SPROTS-RANGE.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" /><img alt="" src="/assets/images/WELLBEING-RANGE.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose you are using bootstrap. You need to wrap your images inside columns. E.g. <div class="col-md-4"><img src="your-image.jpg" alt="" /></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap try something like this

```
<div class="container text-center">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img alt="" src="/assets/images/MEDICAL-RANGE.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img alt="" src="/assets/images/SPROTS-RANGE.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img alt="" src="/assets/images/WELLBEING-RANGE.jpg" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div
```

and with CSS add the properties and styles to your tags

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

Note: you should change the value of `col-sm-*` depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This worked really well ! thanks. However I cant seem to have the whole thing centered properly on Desktop. Seems to be pushed the the right abit.

Comment: @David `class="text-center"` is not working for you?

Comment: it appears not to :(

Comment: whats the best way to contact you

Comment: Here join to the chat in the room "hail hydra" http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/

Answer (score 1):

if you are only using row just because of that you don't need padding between images. So simple is that make separate class for controlling padding of `col-sm`. You should have to use `col-*` inside `row` then it will be work fine.

**CSS**

```
.no-p{
    padding-left:0px;
    paddding-right:0px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container text-center">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 no-p">
             <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97500&w=500&h=500" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 no-p">
             <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97500&w=500&h=500" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 no-p">
             <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97500&w=500&h=500" />
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

View on JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2y3ybff/